# Не отображаются значения на графике с помощью Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, chart.js

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Я описал скрипт для обработки Ajax-запроса, чтобы в конечном итоге отображался график с результатами, но вместо этого выводиться пустой график.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результаты возвращаю с помощью функции render_tempalte в виде одномерного списка со значениями:

```
return render_template("get_data_ajax.html",data=list)
```

Код скрипта:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: "/showDiagram", 
  data: { img : imgsrc},               
  success:function(list){   
    $("#diagram-res").html(list);          
    var chart = new Chart($("#myChart"), {
        type: "bar",
        data: {         
          labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],               
          datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,1)', 'rgba(255,206,86,1)', 'rgba(153,102,255,1)', 'rgba(51,153,102,1)', 'rgba(54,162,235,1)', 'rgba(255,159,64,1)', 'rgba(75,192,192,1)'],
            //data: [8, 119, 45, 5, 9, 10, 6], // Так выводится
            data: [{% for ev in list %} {{ev}}, {% endfor %}],
          }]
        },
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          legend: {display: false},
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Диаграмма"
          }
        }
    });               
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что ветка success не работает. Лично я привык возвращать в ajax json файл при запросе. Не уверен, что ваш способ работоспособен.

Попробуйте потестировать ветку success, поставив `console.log(1);` и `console.log(data);`.

Обязательно дайте знать о ваших результатах.